# Getting User statuses with graph api not working for users with new timeline profile

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I am an iOS developer.

I read the user statuses by the graph api, and it was working fine.

but now for any user having the timeline profile, the return data are empty.
what  should I do??

example for my graph api request:

userID/statuses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out that the problem is that some users have modified their Facebook settings to not allow apps to get the user statuses.